# conditional distribution of minimum of a constant and a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $S$ be an Exponentially distributed random variable with parameter $\lambda$. We define $T=\min(S,L)$ where $L$ is a fixed constant. In this case, what is the conditional distribution $P(t\mid s)$? What is the joint distribution $P(s,t)$?

Comment: You can get proper spacing by using `\mid` instead of `|`.

Answer (score 2):

Since $T$ is a function of $S$, $P(t\mid s)$ is simply $1$ for $t=\min(s,L)$ and $0$ otherwise.

The cumulative distribution function of the joint distribution is

\begin{align}
P(S\ge s\cap T\ge t)
&=
P(S\ge s\cap S\ge t\cap L\ge t)
\\
&=
P(S\ge\max(s,t)\cap L\ge t)
\\
&=
\begin{cases}0&t\gt L\;,\\\exp\left(-\lambda\max(s,t)\right)&t\le L\;.\end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: Then, how can I derive $P(s,t)$ exactly?

Comment: @sisaman: What do you mean by $P(s,t)$?

Comment: I mean their joint density function, $f_{S,T}(s,t)$

Comment: @sisaman: They don't have a joint density function, since the joint cumulative distribution function is not continuous. Are you looking for the joint density in a distribution sense?

Comment: Well, yes actually.

Comment: @sisaman: Have you tried to obtain it by differentiating the cumulative distribution function?